# Change content of files 'proc/sys/kernel/'

Tags: kernel

I know, that linux has particular files, if i change text of this file, i change mode of work OS (or OS is crash). So, many file i can only read. I tried change content, but system protected this file. I can change only hostname (because linux have sethostname syscall). And system request access (password). I tried connect to hard disk flesh with Ubuntu and change content direcly, but i did suprised, becouse i can't looked this files. Directory is empty. So, what is it? I tried write code on Assembler (NASM) and now i want understand structure of OS (security of system file)

Comment: `/proc` is a *pseudo filesystem* - it won't exist on a non-running OS. See `man procfs` for details.

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you